# better way of making sure 4 random values are not equivalent at all?

Tags: c++

i have a qt form that has a multiplication problem and 4 buttons.  the 4 buttons (choices) are randomly generated and so is the question.

i just want to randomize the 4 choices so they are random but none of them are equivalent to the other choices.  this is how i am doing it right now, but it's not working very well:

```
while (choice1 == choice2 || choice1 == choice3 || choice1 == choice4)
    choice1 = (rand() % max) + 1;
while (choice2 == choice1 || choice2 == choice3 || choice2 == choice4)
    choice2 = (rand() % max) + 1;
while (choice3 == choice1 || choice3 == choice2 || choice3 == choice4)
    choice3 = (rand() % max) + 1;
while (choice4 == choice1 || choice4 == choice2 || choice4 == choice3)
    choice4 = (rand() % max) + 1;
```

does anyone else have a better way?

Comment: What do you initialize `choice1` to `choice4` to?

Comment: i initially set them all to the random equation i have up there.  i seeded the rand function with time(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the number of elements is fixed and very small, your overall approach is pretty reasonable. However, the implementation is buggy.

Here is how it can be fixed:

```
choice1 = (rand() % max) + 1;
do { choice2 = (rand() % max) + 1; } while (choice2 == choice1);
do { choice3 = (rand() % max) + 1; } while (choice3 == choice1 || choice3 == choice2);
do { choice4 = (rand() % max) + 1; } while (choice4 == choice1 || choice4 == choice2 || choice4 == choice3);
```

There are better ways to do this if one needs a larger number of elements, or if the number of elements is variable.

Answer (score 10):

Something like (untested, just written here, but you should get the idea):

```
std::set<int> s;

while(s.size() < 4 )
{
    s.insert(rand());
}
```

Comment: @amit: yeah, fixed it, people are just used to `i < size` in for loops ;)

Comment: I reverted my comment, I have the same problem, but you was right at first I think, stop when you actually have 4 elements in set :) anyway, nice approach, +1.

Comment: i will probably utilize this a bit sooner but for right now what the other guy provided is working well.

Comment: Nice, scalable and no need for a compile-time limit. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to shuffle?

http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/misc/random-shuffle.html

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/43868/

Answer (score 1):

Put the four elements in a vector, and call `std::random_shuffle` on it.

Answer (score 0):

How abt this.

```
while (choice1 == choice2 || choice1 == choice3 || choice1 == choice4 || choice2 == choice3 || choice2 == choice4 || choice3 == choice4){    
    choice1 = (rand() % max) + 1; 
    choice2 = (rand() % max) + 1;
    choice3 = (rand() % max) + 1;
    choice4 = (rand() % max) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Works, but could be *very* wasteful (especially if `max` is small).